# Php Exec function

Tags: php, python, exec, return-value

I am unable to understand why the return value in php is not working. Can anybody help me?

```
<?php
exec("xyz.py",$output,$return);
foreach($output as $item){
echo "$item"; 
}
echo $return;
?>
```

The script of xyz.py is as follows:

```
def func():
  print ('Hello')
  return 21
func()
```

The output is always Hello0 no matter what value xyz.py returns

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `sys.exit(21)` in your python script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the PHP [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), the third argument of exec, (`$return` in your example), works like this:

> If the return_var argument is present along with the output argument, then the return status of the executed command will be written to this variable

Since your python program ran fine, the return status should be 0 (no errors).

This might be what you want:

```
import sys
def func():
  print ('Hello')
  return 21
sys.exit(func())
```

Comment: So If I want to return the value the python script is returning to be outputted, can I use exec function for that? Or is there any other function available?

Comment: Is the above what you want?

Comment: No now the output is HelloHello, I wanted output Hello21

Comment: How about modifying your python script, and using your original PHP script?

Answer (score 0):

Return parameter denotes the status of the exec() function and NOT what the program returns .

-1 = error

0 = success

Comment: Is there any function available which can output the return value?

Comment: NO, you can just print the return value in the end instead and get the last line using the passthru().

You can append the return value within quotes and print it. So it will be easier to search and get it.

Answer (score 0):

Append this to your execution string, which allows you to capture any error output:

```
2>&1 &
```

So as per your example:

```
exec('xyz.py 2>&1 &', $output);
echo $output;
```